# Do HTML5 browsers have to be able to properly process HTML4 tags when the tags appear in HTML5 pages?

Tags: html, browser, tags, html5, presentation

According to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200673/11208356), the [HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) requires HTML5 browsers to be able to properly process [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) tags when they are in HTML5 pages.

Unfortunately, the post doesn't very well substantiate this claim. Can someone answer this StackExchange question, and if the answer is 'yes', can they also please substantiate their claim with reference to specific sections of the HTML5 specification in a precise way?

Comment: Understand now that this question is off-topic. Sorry, I didn't realise HTML questions were off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps this question can be moved to another StackExchange site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

No, some tags are not supported anymore. e.g. < menu >
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_menu.asp

Comment: This answer is wrong: [The menu element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-menu-element) Note that w3schools is in no way, shape or form related to the W3C but even w3schools states that the `<menu>` element is in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: It was about browser support, and the tag is not supported anywhere except Firefox although the tag existed till version 4. An anomaly to prove the theory wrong.

Answer (score -1):

[The current HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/) has no "5" in it. [HTML5 is just a buzzword.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/introduction.html#is-this-html5?) So you need to get the version number out of your head and realize that the same people who create browsers are the same people who write the specification and the specification they follow is the current one I linked to. That specification includes elements that have carried over from "HTML4" because they are current and supported. If and when they lose support, they will be [listed here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete).

Comment: So are you saying that there's no such thing as an internet browser that can be termed as a 'current' non-"HTML5" browser that supports "HTML4" (excuse my use of version numbers...)?

Comment: This answer appears to be wrong because within my Chrome browser, if I open an HTML file containing `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head></head><body><table><tr><td align="right">0000000000000</td></tr><tr><td align="right">0</td></tr></table></body></html>`, the table column is aligned to the right, However, this shouldn't be the case if this answer is right, as html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete indicates that the align attribute on td elements is no longer supported in the HTML specification.

Comment: @MarkFernandes The specification is no indication or requirement as to what browsers actually do. It is notice that such features can be removed without notice and one should not rely on their availability.

Comment: @MarkFernandes A browser that is current will follow and support the current HTML specification without any regard to any spec before it. The sole purpose of not removing older features is to not break the web. That is, there are millions of old web sites that are still around and valuable to some people and dropping support for obsolete features can cause harm. But it will eventually happen.